# Xcode.app in /private/var/folders

Tags: xcode

I've found 14GB of files in /private/var/folders. When I looked inside one of them, I found Xcode inside. The path was `/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/668EAA54-DCF6-4F62-9DB1-8F4B5E132200.activeSandbox/Root/Applications/Xcode.app`

It was created in November 2018, but I didn't install Xcode in 2018. I installed it a year later, and even then it was via the Apple Developer website.

Is it safe to remove Xcode here?